# opacity get back default value using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi all I have this script and I want when I'll click other `.circle` opacity get back default value 1
[image]

```
$(this).find('.circle').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({"opacity":"0"},200);
});
```

Comment: Please include some example stripped-down HTML/CSS and possibly a demo on jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted solutions cause that when you click on a selected circle, it blinks.

If you want when click on a selected circle it don't blinks and changes happen only when you switch from one circle to another circle try this:

```
$(this).find('.circle').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('current')){
        $('.circle.current').animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        $('.circle').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $(this).animate({"opacity":"0"},200);
    }
});
```

[**Check JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4tmkf2ea/)

Comment: Thank you for this questions, but I do like this
`$(this).find('.circle').click(function(){
    $('.circle').animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
    $(this).animate({"opacity":"0"},200);
});`

Answer (score 2):

You can set all `.circle` elements opacity to `1` before animating. For example:

```
$(this).find('.circle').click(function(){
    $('.circle').css( 'opacity', '1' );
    $(this).animate({"opacity":"0"},200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $circles = $(this).find('.circle');
$circles.click(function(){
    $circles.animate({"opacity":"1"},200);

    $(this).animate({"opacity":"0"},200);
});
```

**Edit**: cleaned up the code